# CGGradientCreateWithColorComponents and alpha channelI

Tags: ios, core-graphics

I'm creating `CGGradientRef` with [CGGradientCreateWithColorComponents](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/graphicsimaging/Reference/CGGradient/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/c/func/CGGradientCreateWithColorComponents) which is documented to support an alpha channel:

> The number of items in this array should be the product of count and
>   the number of components in the color space. For example, if the color
>   space is an RGBA color space and you want to use two colors in the
>   gradient (one for a starting location and another for an ending
>   location), then you need to provide 8 values in components—red, green,
>   blue, and alpha values for the first color, followed by red, green,
>   blue, and alpha values for the second color.

Below is complete view implementation:

.h

```
@interface AlphaGrad : UIView

@end
```

.m

```
@implementation AlphaGrad

- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame
{
    self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
    if (self) {
    }
    return self;
}

-(void) drawRect:(CGRect)rect {

    CGContextRef ctx = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();

    CGContextSaveGState(ctx);
    CGContextClip(ctx);

    CGGradientRef gradient = [self newGradientWithColors:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:[UIColor blackColor], [UIColor colorWithRed:0 green:0 blue:0 alpha:0.0f], nil]
                                               locations:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:@0, @1, nil]];

    CGContextDrawLinearGradient(ctx, gradient, CGPointMake(rect.origin.x, rect.origin.y),
                                CGPointMake(rect.origin.x, rect.origin.y+rect.size.height), kCGGradientDrawsAfterEndLocation);
    CGGradientRelease(gradient);

    CGContextRestoreGState(ctx);
}

- (CGGradientRef)newGradientWithColors:(NSArray*)colorsArray locations:(NSArray*)locationsArray {

  int count = [colorsArray count];

  CGFloat* components = malloc(sizeof(CGFloat)*4*count);
  CGFloat* locations = malloc(sizeof(CGFloat)*count);

  for (int i = 0; i < count; ++i) {
    UIColor* color = [colorsArray objectAtIndex:i];
    NSNumber* location = (NSNumber*)[locationsArray objectAtIndex:i];
    size_t n = CGColorGetNumberOfComponents(color.CGColor);
    const CGFloat* rgba = CGColorGetComponents(color.CGColor);
    if (n == 2) {
      components[i*4] = rgba[0];
      components[i*4+1] = rgba[0];
      components[i*4+2] = rgba[0];
      components[i*4+3] = rgba[1];
    } else if (n == 4) {
      components[i*4] = rgba[0];
      components[i*4+1] = rgba[1];
      components[i*4+2] = rgba[2];
      components[i*4+3] = rgba[3];
    }
    locations[i] = [location floatValue];
  }

  CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
  CGColorSpaceRef space = CGBitmapContextGetColorSpace(context);
  CGGradientRef gradient = CGGradientCreateWithColorComponents(space, components, locations, count);
  free(components);
  free(locations);
  return gradient;
}
@end
```

The problem is that transparency seems not to be supported, transparent part is drown as white:
[image]

Is it possible to get transparency with `CGGradientRef` to make a "lower" subview partially visible ?

Answer (score 6):

Sorry for a trouble, I didn't set a `backgroundColor` to `clearColor` which solved the problem. Let me leave it here though for a future reference.